# constraint on RowParentId within same table?

Tags: sql-server

How do I specify constraint on my field that allows null but if value exists it should be one of values of primary key within existing table?
Take a look at the code:

```
  CREATE TABLE TestTable 
(
    RowId int IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    RowParentId int NULL, -- < how do I specify constraint that RowParentId if not NULL should be RowId (foreign key to existing table?)
    RowName nvarchar(30),
    RowShortName nvarchar(10)
)
GO
```

I want to be able to generate parent child view without limiting depth and enforcing constraint on existing parent.

Hope I was able to convey what I'm looking for.

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isn't that just a foreign key?

```
RowParentId int NULL references ParentTable (ParentTableIdColumn),
```

if it is not null, then it must be a value from the parent table.

Comment: Exactly - nothing more but a standard, run-of-the-mill foreign key :-)

Comment: Thanks, ParentTable should be substitued with TestTable in my case

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE TestTable
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_testtable_parent
FOREIGN KEY (RowParentId)
REFERENCES TestTable(RowId)
```

Note that keeping a `NULL` in the column is a bad idea, as it's not searcheable by indexes.

You better add a surrogate record with `id = 0`, reference your real root to this record, and exclude it from selects.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a foreign key constraint that references back to the same table. You may want to look into other models for hierarchies though. The linked chain model has a lot of problems in SQL. Do a Google on "Joe Celko hierarchies" and you should be able to find information on other ways to model a hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a *foreign key*. There are several ways to do this, but the simplest way for a single key like this would be to add the following after the workld "null" for that column:

```
references table_name (column_name)
```

You may need to add the words "foreign key" before that, I can't remember. Either way that should take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

ALTER TABLE [dbo].TestTable   WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_TestTable_RowId_TestTable_RowParentId] FOREIGN KEY(RowParentId) REFERENCES TestTable(RowId)